# firewalld / ufw defaults - firewall access

Tags: networking, firewall, default

I am using ub 20.0.4.2 - a pretty standard load to play with.
vm was a standard load, 4 nics (eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3) with fixed IP / 8gb. and eth0 goes to the gateway, and DNS is 9.9.9.9

Installed firewalld did not add any services, ports, or make any changes - so a pretty standard default config.

moved eth0, eth1 to "public" zone
moved eth2, eth3 to "internal" zone

Here is the question.
I did an update and upgrade, and also installed net-plan - everything worked fine - and that is the question.
I thought update used port 80, and upgrade used port 53

Are these working because of the default  -services: dhcpv6-client ??
So if that is the case then that means port 53 is open right? Or is it only open for system services - like upgrade,

thanks
thom